# How to make a list where the i-th element appears i times?

Tags: python, list, sum, extend

It could be very easy question but i can't make it through this question. For example if n = 5, i want the answer list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]. If n = 6, i want the answer list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]

The below code is what i made first time, but i even wonder this format is right to use.

```
rules = []
rules.extend([x for x in range(n)])
```

if i use this kind of code, it only makes list =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...... , n] Should i change the x format to another things?

```
rules = []
rules.extend([[x] * x for x in range(n)])
```

or if i use this kind of code, it makes list in the list format like this, list = [[1], [2], [2], [3], [3], [3]]

Comment: `[i for i in range(n) for _ in range(i)]`, a double for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> rules = [i for i in range(1, n + 1) for __ in range(i)]
>>> rules
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: This really works simple and quick. Really thank you ruohola!